# How to stream a huge string fast in node with back-pressure support?

Tags: node.js, stream

The real use-case is sending a huge string through SSH, but for simplicity, I'll demonstrate it with two processes. See the code below.

When I convert this huge stream to a Readable stream and pipe it to the child process, it sends very small chunks of data, just a few bytes (~80) each and as a result, the transfer rate is extremely slow.

If, as an alternative, I write directly to the child process (`stdin.write`), it's super fast and each chunk is the correct size - 8KB. However, this method doesn't support back-pressure, so with a huge string and a slow consumer, it gets overwhelmed.

My question is, how do I pipe the string to the child process but with the normal chunk size.

parent.js

```
const stream = require('stream');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn('node', ['child.js'], {});
const strSize = 1000000;
const hugeStr = [...Array(strSize)].map(i=>(~~(Math.random()*36)).toString(36)).join('');
console.log('PARENT: hugeStr size: ', hugeStr.length);

const readable = stream.Readable.from(hugeStr);
readable.pipe(child.stdin);

// an alternative to the pipe, but with no support for back-pressure
// child.stdin.write(hugeStr);
// child.stdin.end();
```

child.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

const debug = (str) => fs.writeFileSync('debug.log', `\n${str}`, { flag: 'a' });

function getDataFromStdin() {
  let data = '';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk.toString();
      const size = chunk.byteLength;
      debug(`DATA ${size}B. ${Math.floor(size / 1024)}KB`);
    });

    process.stdin.on('end', () => {
      const size = data.length;
      debug(`END TOTAL DATA ${size}B. ${Math.floor(size / 1024)}KB ${Math.floor(size / 1024 / 1024)}MB`);
      resolve();
    });

    process.stderr.on('data', (dataErr) => debug(`child error ${dataErr.toString()}`));
  });

}

getDataFromStdin()
  .then(() => debug('CHILD: COMPLETED'))
  .catch(err => debug(`CHILD ERR: ${err}`))
```

Comment: As far as I can see from the logs of your program, when using `pipe` everything works correctly and `Node.js` first transfers a chunk of one byte size, and then transfers a chunk of `highWaterMark - 1` size (by default, it is 16384 - 1). The fact that `Node.js` transfers 1 byte first is due to the device of `Node.js` streams, but nobody prevents you from writing to `child.stdin` using `.write` and listening for the `drain` event to avoid back-pressure.

Comment: Don't listen to data don't use the stream in flowing mode listen to readable instead and set the watermarks

Comment: @RustamD9RS, when I look into the log, the first chunk is indeed 1 byte, however, all the rest are some random numbers varying from 1byte to ~100 bytes. E.g. from my last running, the first is 1B, then 59B, 1B, 22B, 19B, and so on. I don't see any number close to 16384. I also tried to set the `highWaterMark` to a larger number, but it didn't help. About using the `.write` method, yes, I tried it and with my real use-case (ssh), it made some troubles, so I prefer to use pipes, which works fine but very slow. I don't get why the chunks are that small.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I tried that as well, in the child.js file, instead of listening to the `data`, I listen to `readable` and ask for data by `process.stdin.read()`, making it non-flowing mode. However, the same exact issue persists. Meaning, if in the parent I use `pipe`, it sends very small chunks. Regardless of the number I put in the `.read()`. If I don't use pipe, I still have to manage the back-pressure myself and with my ssh situation even with drain I got problems.

Comment: @David, Are you talking about the above example or SSH transfer? If your example transmits chunks of ~ 100 bytes, then it looks very strange, since Node.js should transmit chunks of highWaterMark size. Please tell me your Node.js version and what OS you are using.

Comment: @RustamD9RS, I'm talking about the above example, not about the SSH. My OS is Mac OS Catalina. And yes! you're right! It's related to the node version. I used v12.7.0. I checked a few versions. It is fixed in 12.17.0, 14.5.0. It fails on 10.21.0, 12.7.0, 12.12.0. Note that I need both processes to have a working version to make it fast, which is unfortunate for me, as I need all our users to have certain node version. Any idea how can I make this Readable string fast on those node versions? Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I continued testing a few more node versions and I noticed that it happens on v12.15.0 but not on 12.16.0. In the changelog, I found the commit that seems to be the issue here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/30912 they previously sent the string one character at a time.

Comment: Just to keep this up-to-date. There is an npm package string-to-stream, which works on all versions and the chunks are the right size. Sadly, on my real case of the SSH, it doesn't work well. I don't have time for this for now. I might open a new issue later.

Comment: Use the package I tod Gilad about - sonic-boom

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I checked it out, but it is for files and file descriptors. In our use-case, there are no files involved. The objects are converted to a string and streamed into the SSH.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file